# Import a Key to Azure Key Vault (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, elliptic-curve

I'm having issues in importing an EC key to Azure Key Vault while using the SDK.

Code:

```
var ecKey = Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var privateKey = ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes().ToHex();

var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey);
var privateKeyInt =
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(+1, privateKeyBytes);
var parameters = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
var ecPoint = parameters.G.Multiply(privateKeyInt).Normalize();
var privateKeyX = ecPoint.Normalize().XCoord.ToBigInteger()
        .ToByteArrayUnsigned();
var privateKeyY = ecPoint.Normalize().YCoord.ToBigInteger()
        .ToByteArrayUnsigned();

var jwk = new JsonWebKey(new [] { KeyOperation.Sign, KeyOperation.Verify, });
jwk.CurveName = KeyCurveName.P256K;
jwk.KeyType = KeyType.Ec;
jwk.D = privateKeyBytes;

jwk.X = privateKeyX;
jwk.Y = privateKeyY;

await keyClient.ImportKeyAsync(keyName, jwk, cancellationToken);`
```

Error from Azure, which is not very helpful in knowing exactly what is wrong:

> Azure.RequestFailedException: EC key is not valid - cannot instantiate crypto service.
> Status: 400 (Bad Request)
> ErrorCode: BadParameter

Note: On this example I generate a new key, but normally it would be an existing private key of ours.

Do you guys have any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: I assume you have a reason to use some other SDK, but why not just creating the Key with the KeyVault SDK itself? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.keyclient.createkeyasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: It was just an example of a key, on my use case it would be an existing private key. Edited and added that note

Comment: `ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes()` seems to be the private key, `privateKey` the hex encoded key and `privateKeyBytes` the Utf-8 encoding of the hex encoded key. However, the second parameter in `new BigInteger()` should not be the Utf-8 encoding of the hex encoded key (`privateKeyBytes`), but the key itself (`ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was solved with [Topaco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75854557/import-a-key-to-azure-key-vault-c#comment133805866_75854557).

What I was doing wrong is that I was encoding the private key and then converting to an array of bytes.

Correct code:

```
var ecKey = Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var privateKey = ecKey.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes();
var parameters = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
var privateKeyInt =
    new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(+1, privateKey);
var ecPoint = parameters.G.Multiply(privateKeyInt).Normalize();
var privateKeyX = ecPoint.Normalize().XCoord.ToBigInteger()
    .ToByteArrayUnsigned();
var privateKeyY = ecPoint.Normalize().YCoord.ToBigInteger()
    .ToByteArrayUnsigned();

var jwk = new JsonWebKey(new [] { KeyOperation.Sign, KeyOperation.Verify, })
{
    CurveName = KeyCurveName.P256K,
    KeyType = KeyType.Ec,
    D = privateKey,
    X = privateKeyX,
    Y = privateKeyY,
};

await keyClient.ImportKeyAsync(keyName, jwk, cancellationToken);
```